# SetDefaultFont .Net Core 6.0 WinForms Not Correct at Design-Time

Tags: vb.net, winforms, fonts, .net-6.0

When setting the `Application.SetDefaultFont()` method in a WinForms, VB.Net 6.0 Application, everything works fine at runtime, but in design-time the controls all still default to Segoe 9pt. Is there a way to make them use the new application wide font in design-time. Without it, I can't properly layout the screen since the size is different for text and thus, auto-size controls are different as well.

Code to set the font is:

```
Public Module Startup

    <STAThread>
    Public Sub Main()
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.PerMonitorV2)
        Application.SetDefaultFont(New Font(New FontFamily("Proxima Nova"), 12.0F))
        Application.Run(New Form1())
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Controls that make use of a *default Font*, inherit the Font from the Parent, up to the top-level Container. Set the same Font to the Form, in case you don't see that Font used by default.

Comment: But doesn't doing that defeat the purpose of having a simple method like setdefaultfont in the first place? If I need to set a specific font on each form, then the controls would, as you say, inherit that font .. but I thought the point of being able to set an application wide font is so I don't need to do that? Help me understand if I am missing something. Thanks

Comment: Actually, this setting appears not to be working at this time in VB.Net Projects, while it does work in C# Projects. In the Project's configuration file, setting, e.g., `<ApplicationDefaultFont>Microsoft YaHei UI, 9pt, style=regular</ApplicationDefaultFont>` and rebuilding, changes the default Font in all Forms and also changes `Application.SetDefaultFont()` to the corresponding values in the `ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize()` method of the auto-generated bootstrap. -- An identical VB.Net Project, either initialized with Application Framework or a written Sub Main, does not.

Comment: Hi Jimi, Ya I just found an article that says basically the same thing. It was written back in Dec 2021 and says Microsoft is working on the issue ... ya...I'm gunna hold my breath. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Yep. As Visual Studio 2022 v.17.2.0 (latest), a C# Project sports the new Project Configuration interface, which allows to set most properties of the Project's Configuration file (without manual intervention, that is), while a VB.Net Project still has the old interface. Which may suggest that the Compiler is not updated to support these features entirely, at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jimi, Seems you are right. Found an article from 2021 saying Microsoft is "aware of the issue and working on a solution"...hmm not going to hold my breath. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).